# Is there something like the FileSystemWatcher for Sql Server Tables?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i would like my windows service (to be written in .NET) to recognize when new rows are added to a specific table, but instead of pulling the data from the sql-server i would like to use a server push model.

does somebody has a hint for me how to achieve this?
i am using sql server 2005.

tia

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's also the ADO.NET [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953.aspx) mechanism if you're using client side ADO.NET with C# or VB.NET

> A  SqlDependency object can be
>   associated with a  SqlCommand in order
>   to detect when query results differ
>   from those originally retrieved. You
>   can also assign a delegate to the
>   OnChange event, which will fire when
>   the results change for an associated
>   command. You must associate the 
>   SqlDependency with the command before
>   you execute the command. The
>   HasChanges property of the 
>   SqlDependency can also be used to
>   determine if the query results have
>   changed since the data was first
>   retrieved.

You basically associate a `SqlDependency` with your SqlCommand, and provide an event handler that gets called when values that make up the result set of that SqlDependency change.

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStatement, _conn))
{ 
   cmd.Notification = null;

   SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);

   dependency.OnChange += 
       new OnChangeEventHandler(OnChange);

    ......
}
```

In the event handler, you can then do whathever you need to do.

```
void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
  SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;

  (do whatever you need to do - e.g. reload the data)

}
```

Marc

Comment: This is a great solution and very well may be the best in your situation, however, I'm pretty sure the "Server" (SQL server) is not "Pushing" anything... I'm curious, though, what *is* going on under the covers?

Comment: @Mike: the server **is** pushing. See here: http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/

Comment: @Marc: actually Query Notifications are available to ODBC and OleDB clients too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx

Comment: @Remus: excellent write-up about Sql Dependency! May I quote that in the future? :-)

Answer (score 3):

The closest you'll get in Sql Server 2005 is a trigger.  Sql Server 2008 also has change data capture.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171157(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Given that Notification Services were swiftly dropped again for the 2008 version, I'd not be recommending a new solution based on that.

As marc_s posted, the SqlDependency/SqlNotificationRequest classes can be used from managed code.

Comment: I didn't know it was dropped. It is not like I have touched it in a couple of years. However, the OP explicitly states that he is using SQL Server 2005, so it would not be a problem. That said, you are right about marc_s idea being a better one. It seems so much better to not to share the responsability with an external service.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger with a [webservice call](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2008/11/11/calling-a-web-service-from-sql-server-2005/) from the database. But I have no idea how bad (if any) impact will be against the database.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class to monitor changes in database tables - it has [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511806/how-do-i-clean-sqldependency-from-sql-server-memory/) with memory leaks. However, you can use your own realization with DDL triggers and [SQL Service Broker API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848765.aspx) or use one of open source projects, e.g. [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs):

```
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

Hope this helps.