# Detecting and reloading updated application parameters at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, validation, iis

I am working on an ASP.NET web application(using .NET 4.5 and C#).The application deals with lot of units (for measuring like KG,Litre,KM etc). So based on the selected unit we have to implement some allowed range.This values can be configured without much effort.
We identified two solutions for this

1. Keeping a configuration xml.
   Suppose the values in xml, does it requires an iisreset or any other thing which can take the site down for some time, if we are changing the xml file to change some validation.
2. Keeping in Db, then use SQL dependency caching. So an update to DB can reflect the caching values.SO i believe if we change the values, it will update the cache. How much complex is this and does it effect the performance ?

It will be great helpful, if we have some other method to achieve this.

**EDIT**

Dear All
I am not having a technical issue. I need a solution to handle this situation. I identified two solutions. I need someone to review this. or provide any other better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad. See [FileSystemWatcher vs polling to watch for file changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes) for detecting XML file changes and [Is there something like the FileSystemWatcher for Sql Server Tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311924/is-there-something-like-the-filesystemwatcher-for-sql-server-tables) for SqlDependency.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am not having a technical issue. I need a solution to handle this situation. I identified two solutions. I need someone to review this. or provide any other better solution.

Comment: You have two possible solutions and you should have a list of requirements, so you can evaluate (by prototyping and benchmarking) the two implementations. There's little we can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: @CodeCaster these are the solutions I know, but i am expecting some one to saying that there is another solution etc. I did the poc and its works fine. but to make sure that I am following the correct way, because after some day, if someone else is working then they dont feel this a bad approach